# Set custom timezone only for return queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timezone, utc

Is there any way to get the time from my database at my given timezone only for return query. On SET or UPDATE I want to use the UTC timezone as before.

Already used

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+6:00';
```

But it changes my write timezone too.

Comment: If you're using MySQL with an application, then what would be wrong with handling this behavior there?

Comment: that can be one way to do that. But i was wondering if there is any way to handle it from the DB.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what's a return query

Comment: By return query I mean when getting the data from db.